# MapView MyLocationOverlay First Run issue

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-location

I use location services in my app. If I send longitude and latitude to emulator via DDMS, blue dot animate to there. But if I close the app and restart again, blue dot doesn't seem. If you see blue dot, you have to send new longitude and latitude. 
**I want to show blue dot every time when app start.**

What can I do ?

**onCreate:**

```
mc = mapView.getController();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc.setZoom(15);
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay); 
        myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mc.animateTo(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
                }
        });

        mapView.postInvalidate();

lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();       
        provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
            }
```

**onLocationChanged(Location location)**

```
String PK="";

        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
        try{

            List<Address> adresler = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if(adresler.size()>0){
                Address adres = adresler.get(0);
                boolean sayi = false;
                for(int i=0;i<adres.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++){
                    if(i!=2){
                        sb.append(adres.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        String full = adres.getAddressLine(i).toString();
                        char chars[] = full.toCharArray();
                        for(int k=0;k<chars.length;k++){
                            sayi = Character.isDigit(chars[k]);
                            if(sayi){
                                PK=PK+chars[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }   
                adresString = sb.toString();
                new gpsYerBilgisiAS(PK).execute();
            }
        }
            catch(IOException e){

            }
        }
```

**onResume and onPause**

```
@Override   
    protected void onResume() {  
        super.onResume();  
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);      
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();

    }
    @Override   
    protected void onPause() {    
        super.onPause();
        lm.removeUpdates(this); 
        myLocOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emulator, you have to send position each time you want to call onLocationChanged method.
On device, it's automatically done if GPS is open. But i will only display "blue dot" when your device receives a location data via GPS or network.

Comment: selam, türkçe anlatabilmek daha iyi olacak :) Emulator üzerinde longitude ve latitude gönderdiğimde konuma hareketleniyor. Ancak telefona attığımda eğer lokasyon değişmediyse mavi nokta çıkmıyor. Lokasyon aynıda kalsa değişsede ben mavi noktayı göstermek istiyorum. Aynı konumda kaldığımda zaten onLocationChange fonksiyonuna girmiyor.

Comment: Abicim, `MyLocationOverlay` zaten kendisi bir `SensorThread` açiyor. Onunla `LocationListener`'ın alakası yok zaten. Bunu unutma. I was telling this person that a locationoverlay opens it's own SensorThread.

Comment: (Translation of my answer above)
Şöyle, emülatörde GPS güncellemesini manuel yapmak zorundasın. Yani her seferinde konum bilgisi göndermen lazım. Aygıt üzerinde ise bu otomatik olarak yapılıyor. Yani bunun için endişelenmene gerek yok.

Comment: Şuanda HTC One X , HTC Wildfire S ve Samsung Galaxy Wonder modellerinde deniyorum uygulamayı. One X ICS kullanıyor diğer ikisi gingerbread. Gingerbreadlerde sorun yok lokasyon aynıda olsa her seferinde lokasyonu veriyor ve mavi nokta gözüküyor. Ama ICS de tepki yok. Boş haritaya bakıyorum :)

Comment: @tolgap
onLocationChanged is always called when your MyLocationOverlay instance receives a location. Try to create your own class extending MyLocationOverlay class and override its onLocationChanged method and see.

Melih
Telefon ayarlarından GPS modülünü aktive etmeyi dene. Muhtemelen aktif değildir.

Comment: hayır aktif, zaten gps aktif olmadığında yönlendirilecek başka bir sayfa var. Map sayfasının başlangıcında gps kontrolü yapıyorum zaten aktifse map sayfasına giriyor. Sorunun ne olduğunu cidden bilmiyorum. Bu arada sayfa açıldığında GPS simgeside yukarıda beliriyor zaten ama herhangi bir veri alışverişi yapmıyor sanırım. Google maps i açtım orda konumu buluyor.

Comment: Telefonu internete bağlayıp deneyebilir misin? İnternete erişimi olursa network üzerinden konumunu bulup mavi noktayı gösterir. Eğer bu çalışırsa telefonun GPS cihazında sorun var demektir. Ya da kapalı mekandaysan GPS sinyali almıyor olabilir.

Comment: Şimdi öncelikle telefon internete bağlı. Mavi nokta hala gözükmüyor. GPS cihazında sorun olsa google maps de de konumu bulmaması gerekmez mi ? Google maps de konum buluyor. Kapalı mekandayım ancak diğer iki cihaz konumu buluyor. Şuanda bir galaxy note üzerinde de deniyorum ICS yüklü, ve onda da sorun olmadan mavi nokta her şekilde çıkıyor. Sorun HTC One X de ama gerçekten anlamıyorum sorunun ne olduğunu. Yardımın için teşekkürler yapıcak bir şey yok sanırım.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `onResume()` like this:

```
protected void onResume() {
    ....
    myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay); 
    myLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mc.animateTo(myLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
    });
    ....
}
```

And it will work the way you want. This is how I have it at the moment in my own app.

Comment: No, your app has that in the `onCreate()`. Just put it in `onResume()`. Even if it hasn't the desired effect for you, it will be a better way.

Comment: I understand and I did what you say. But there isn't any change. Thanks for showing the better way , but I didn't solve problem yet :)

Comment: Edited my answer. I forgot an important line. Can you try it now?

Comment: I noticed that it and fix your code but there isn't any change.